# adjust postgres query not to return already fetched data

Tags: database, postgresql, geolocation, gis, postgis

I have the below query, I am trying to get all points that are within 100m of each, the query generally works ok, but it will return 'duplicates'. (the table location_signals is a table that contains millions of lat/lon records & their timestamp, st_setsrid is the geography column, p_key is the primary key)

For example, the query would return 'point 1 has points 2 3 4 5 within 100m', and it will also return 'point 2 has points 1 3 4 5 within 100m'.

I want to exclude all points that were already retrieved. 
So in this case, points 2 3 4 5 would not be scanned again if they were returned within point 1 already.

Any help on how to do that would be great, thanks!

```
        SELECT a.p_key, a."Lat",a."Lon", b.p_key,b."Lat",b."Lon",b.timestamp,b.st_setsrid 
        FROM location_signals as a, location_signals as b 
        WHERE ST_DWITHIN (a.st_setsrid, b.st_setsrid, 100, false) 
        AND a.p_key != b.p_key; -- don't check on self
```

Comment: `AND a.p_key < b.p_key` is the trivial symmetry-breaker.

Comment: i have tried this, it solved part of the problem, but i still have duplicates , for example if IDs  2 3 4 5 where returned for the ID 1, for ID 2 I am still getting 3 4 5..how can I exclude those?

Answer (score 0):

You may get what you want using DISTINCT ON. This will a single row with the mentioned columns within the distinct clause.

```
SELECT distinct on (b."Lat",b."Lon"), a.p_key, a."Lat",a."Lon", b.p_key,b.timestamp,b.st_setsrid 
    FROM location_signals as a, location_signals as b 
    WHERE ST_DWITHIN (a.st_setsrid, b.st_setsrid, 100, false) 
    AND a.p_key != b.p_key;
```